# How do I get the some of the values from 2 foreign keys in a table?

Tags: derby

I've spent a good amount of time on this but, still have no idea as to the sql query I can use to get the student name, and class name from the payments_per_student table.

edit: This using JPA work with this DB. Knowing the JPA way as well SQl way would be interesting. I'm currently researching the JPA way.

payments_per_student:

```
PAYMENTS_PER_STU_ID                           
STUDENTS_STUDENT_ID                           
FAMILY_ACCOUNT_FAMILY_ID                        
REASON_FOR_PAYMENT                          
AMOUNT                                                     
DATE_PAID                                                 
CLASSES_CLASS_ID                                    
ACTIVE_IN_CLASS                                      
NOTES
```

The second is, Classes:

```
CLASS_ID                               
CLASS_NAME                      
DAY_OF_CLASS                  
TIME_OF_CLASS             
DURATION_OF_CLASS   
PRICE_PER_CLASS         
PRICE_PER_TERM          
PRICE_PER_YEAR          
NOTES
```

The third table is, Students:

```
STUDENT_ID             
FIRST_NAME           
LAST_NAME           
FAMILY_ACCOUNT_ID   
SEX_TYPE          
NAME_PREF           
DATE_OF_BIRTH      
PERFORMANCE_STU          
HEALTH_ISSUES      
NOTES
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start:

```
select S.FIRST_NAME,    C.CLASS_NAME,    C.DURATION_OF_CLASS
FROM STUDENTS S
INNER JOIN PAYMENTS_PER_STUDENT A ON S.STUDENT_ID=PAYMENTS_PER_STU_ID
INNER JOIN CLASSES_R C ON A .CLASSES_CLASS_ID = C.CLASS_ID;
```

I found [it](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Exercises/Scientists) + [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language).